# iOS - version history

Tags: ios, software-update, versions, history

Is there an official version history for iOS?

The best similar thing I have found is on Wikipedia: [iOS Version History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history#iOS_9)

Is there something similar, that is official? I would like to know what could changed for iPhone, when upgrading from iOS 9.0 to iOS 9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [an official Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1842?locale=en_US) detailing the changes in each update from iOS 9.0 to 9.0.2.

If Apple treats this page the same way they've treated past iOS changelog pages, that link will contain every update from iOS 9.0 to whatever the final update before 9.1 is. What I found for iOS 8 was a different webpage for every 8.x update.